# Add timestamp in adjacent cell when cell equals a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

I have a project tracker tool. Column K has a drop down menu for when a Task is completed. The drop down menu has the option of setting the task as "Not Delivered" or "Delivered". I would like to program Column L so that whenever someone chooses a task as "Delivered", I have a timestamp of that action. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a script attached to your spreadsheet. See [the tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) if you're new to Google Apps-Script in Spreadsheets.

Here's a picture of a spreadsheet that does what you're describing:

[image: Screenshot of working spreadsheet]

The script below will react to changes in Column K by writing or clearing a timestamp in Column L. Since it's called for every change in your spreadsheet, the first thing it does is check whether a change we care about has occurred, and exits if not.

```
/**
 * This function is an auto-trigger, because of its name. It will be
 * invoked on every change in the spreadsheet. The only change that
 * we're interested in is in Column K, and we want to put a timestamp
 * into Column L if the value selected for Column K is "Completed".
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var ColK = 11;  // Column Number of "K"

  var changedRange = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (changedRange.getColumn() == ColK) {
    // An edit has occurred in Column K
    var state = changedRange.getValue();
    var adjacent = event.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(changedRange.getRow(),ColK+1);
    var timestamp = new Date(); // Get the current time
    // We'll do something different, depending on the selected value
    switch (state) {
      case "Completed":
        // Write timestamp into adjacent cell
        adjacent.setValue(timestamp);
        break;
      case "Not Completed":
        // Erase timestamp in adjacent cell
        adjacent.clearContent();
        break;
      default:
        // Something we didn't expect
        adjacent.setValue("*ERROR*");
        break
    }
  }
}
```

To do: This script assumes you've changed just one cell, which means that copying values to multiple cells isn't properly handled.

Comment: How would you use this where instead of "Completed" the cell changes from blank/empty to filled for the time stamp to be created.