# Create automatic timestamp when adjacent cell has specific value

Tags: excel, timestamp

I am trying to create a snazzy to do list in Excel. I want to automatically generate a time stamp in column I when column K (in the same row) is equal to 1.

The only suggestions I can find are timestamps that are generated when ANY changes are made, not a specific value entered.

Here's an example of what I want to do based on a google apps question:

[Add timestamp in adjacent cell when cell equals a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390558/add-timestamp-in-adjacent-cell-when-cell-equals-a-specific-value)

Comment: Is the value in column **K** the result of an equation or an input??

Comment: You can try =IF(K1=1,NOW(),""). But, the timestamp value will change whenever any changes are made AND K1 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the values in column **K** result from formulas then use this event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("K:K"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If r.Value = 1 And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                r.Offset(0, 1) = Date
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

If the values in column **K** are typed or filled by drop-down selection, then use this event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Target
    If Intersect(Range("K:K"), r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If r.Value <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If r.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r.Offset(0, 1) = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(C3<>"",IF(B3="",NOW(),B3),"")
```

In excel 2007, you can go to office button > excel options > formulas > iteration area and turn iteration on 
what it does is it checks cell C3 and whenever it is not empty it runs the circular formula which creates the time in B3